# SelectMany in Linq to entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I was looking at some examples in microsoft site about linq and I see an example that I need to modify!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758.aspx#SelectManyCompoundfrom3

```
public void Linq16()
{
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();

var orders =
    from c in customers
    from o in c.Orders
    where o.OrderDate >= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1)
    select new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate };

ObjectDumper.Write(orders);
}
```

Insted of having a select that retrives the CustomerID, OrderID and OrderDate I want to select the CustomerID and a `System.Collection.Generic.List<int>` that contains all the orders for that user! Essentially I want to group my orders by CustomerID, but i noticed that linq to entity does not allow a `.ToList(object)` inside the select.

I want something like this...

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomerList();

var orders =
    from c in customers
    from o in c.Orders
    where o.OrderDate >= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1)
    select new xpto
    {
      TheCostumerID = c.CustomerID, 
      CostumerOrders = o.Select(i=>i.OrderID).ToList(),
    };
```

...but the .ToList() is a big problem, at least for me.

Comment: What is the problem with the "ToList"?

Comment: .ToList() inside a select in linq to entity seems not to work!

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to group by clause?

```
 from orders in context.Orders
 group orders by orders.CustomerID into ordersGroup
 select new { CustomerID = ordersGroup.Key, 
              Orders = ordersGroup };
```

Let me know if it is not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the more functional syntax to be more concise, but I'd make use of GroupBy like this:

```
DateTime minDate = new DateTime(1998, 1, 1);

ordersEntities = entities.Customers.GroupJoin(entities.Orders, // Table to join with
    customer => customer.Id, order => order.CustomerId, // Properties to match on
    (customer, orders) => new {
        Customer = customer,
        Orders = orders.Where(o => o.Date > minDate)
    });
```

And then using ToList() to pop out of LINQ-to-entities and into LINQ-to-objects (with an eye on how this affects the actual SQL queries going to your database, of course):

```
return ordersEntities.ToList()
    .Select(oe => new {
        Customer = oe.Customer,
        Orders = oe.ToList()
    });
```